# white space across webpage only in mozilla

Tags: css, firefox

I've just started a new project for my clan. First i worked in chrome, but one of my friends told me there was a strange problem with the site. At the top of the page there is a white space, but this happens only in Mozilla. When i inspect it, it says it's apart html. I've triple checked the css for margins and paddings, but i couldn't find the problem. 
Here is the CSS:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8jNXRky-LW_aUw4Z1hXVlVwbHM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: the css file on its own is useless, we need either a link to the live website or a jsfiddle as mentioned above, or post the code here

Comment: i can post a link to my website, but i can't host it for too long

Comment: http://79.113.39.185/pgs/index.html

Comment: That site looks identical to me in both Chrome 26 and Firefox 24

Comment: here is a screenshot http://imgur.com/a0eF18U maybe my rez is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a strange issue. I see it in chrome also. It seems to go away if I add `display:inline-block` to `.content`

I'm looking through it atm but i am unable to find why it requires this. will edit if I find

EDIT:

its the span inside `.content` it has a lot of margins / padding on top of it, it is shoving everything else down. You need to modify this

Comment: for me it's the same even if a remove the span. take a look now.

Comment: Sorry wasnt on my computer. On chrome i put display:none and it all shifted up as u wanted it to display. Also on chrome if u inspect element on the span, u can see the orange box surrounding the span covers this white area that is appearing